# DiscordJS v12 Cannot send messages to this user

Tags: logging, discord, discord.js

```
let channelID = "951015988332232726";
let guildID = "911491194654175242";
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if(message.channel.type === 'dm'){
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(client.guilds.cache.get(guildID).members.cache.get(message.author.id).displayName)
    .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())
    .setColor(ee.color)
    .setDescription(message.content)
    .setFooter(ee.footertext, ee.footericon);
    client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send(embed);

    let embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Thank You')
    .setColor(ee.color)
    .setDescription('Your response is being carefully recorded! <:check:947079937372872704>')
    .setFooter(ee.footertext, ee.footericon);
    message.author.send(embed2)
  }
});
```

I am creating a dm logging system but when the bot messages the user it gives the error `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user` , although users are recieving the message.
The Bot Replying Fine:
https://prnt.sc/fwVMHzOMBaID
The Bot Logging Fine:
https://prnt.sc/hvce78pKaZtG
The Error:
https://prnt.sc/XAw7AV6i-2o6
I cannot figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user has blocked the bot or doesn't allow DM (in general or in the server the bot is present) then it cannot work. You should try catch when sending the message.

Comment: I have dms enabled and have mutual servers with the bot, and i have tried https://pastebin.com/wDQYsUr5

Comment: I have access denied to that pastebin

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3Z2EmBH3

Comment: fixed it, adding `if (message.author.bot) return;` resolved it